# heroku Idle connection timeout on heroku socket.io server based

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

Sometimes my socket server raise the following problem:

Here the heroku log:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path=/socket.io/1/websocket/RcjG0Zjot1U3uwLWX9SI 
host=www.*********.** request_id=69f5aa39-255b-4871-a928-1548ef2fdd4f 
fwd="217.200.201.210" dyno=web.1 connect=0 service=306473 status=503 bytes=870
```

I'm using socket.io library version 0.9.x and node 0.8.x.
It's hosted on heroku with the websocket activated (heroku labs:enable websockets -a myapp).
I'm not using xhr-polling

Here's how I've implemented the socket server:

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  if(pathname == "/") pathname = "index.html";
  if(pathname.indexOf("/chat/") != -1  ) pathname = "index.html";
  var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', pathname);
  path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    if(!exists) {
      response.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
      response.write("404 Not Found");
      response.end();
      return;
    }
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': mime.lookup(filename) });
    fs.createReadStream(filename, {
      'flags': 'r',
      'encoding': 'binary',
      'mode': 0666,
      'bufferSize': 4 * 1024
    }).addListener("data", function(chunk) {
      response.write(chunk, 'binary');
    }).addListener("close", function() {
      response.end();
    });
  });
});


socket_calls = new socket_calls(webSocket, io, connectedUsers,clients );
webSocket.sockets.on('connection',socket_calls.socket_callback_func );
httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, "0.0.0.0");
```

This problem seems to be present only on 3g connection and it's reported by some clients who sistematically can't connect to the server.

I've tryed to reproduce the problem on several devices with 3g connection and wi-fi connection using "network link conditioner" to simulate a bad connection, but I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: So where's your question? What do you want to do about it? I think there are always bad clients, not always you can fix them. And socket.io should reconnect if not receiving heartbeats.

Comment: what it's strange is that once a device can't connect, it can't connect systematically. 
the same device can't connect trougth 3g but can connect on wifi, then retesting on 3g it can't connect another time.

Comment: It might be due to a high packet loss that this is happening. In Malaysia sometimes when I get connected to a edge network, packet loss is enough to keep me connected but not get anything done. This might be the case in here. The user gets connected and gets the files and stuff. But in the middle packet loss gets high, TCP socket still remains and pretends to be connected, but high packet loss prevents anything from passing.

Comment: Hi guys, I had this issue too and after a lot of testing and debugging I realized that this is was just a Heroku Router "thing" since my app was working perfectly fine but I kept getting those errors. I don't want to duplicate the answer so I'll leave the link here in case it's useful for anyone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728030/heroku-h15-error-on-web-socket-close/59941248#59941248

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it.
The problem was present only on 3g connection with TIM career.

I've disabled the websocket support from heroku command line tools and I've enabled xhr-polling on socket.io.

Comment: Similar problem with my ISP. I used a VPN as a workaround and it worked.

Comment: How did you disabled websocket support on heroku? I'm getting the same error with any kind of connection.