# Socket.io on Heroku random H15 message

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

#### My setup:

- We've got an app using [socket.io](http://socket.io/), hosted on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home) on a hobby dyno.

#### The problem:

The clients randomly disconnect and reconnect. I've traced this to Heroku logging to me an H15 Error:

So, here's what Heroku says about this:

> The dyno did not send a full response and was terminated due to 55
>   seconds of inactivity.

#### Why I find this weird:

- Socket.io sends by default a *heartbeat* message. The default `pingInterval` is `25000ms`. Therefore the above error message should not appear under normal circumstances.

What scenarios might be causing this?

Comment: Hi! I just experienced the same issue and finally got to a conclusion after a lot of debugging and testing. Yes, Socket.io will handle the heartbeat on its own with you having to do anything. What happens is that Heroku Router considers the WebSocket connection "pending", not timed-out because the heartbeat prevents that. I described what's going on in detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728030/heroku-h15-error-on-web-socket-close/59941248#59941248, I hope this helps more people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this great article](https://lxcid.com/2017/06/03/socket.io-heroku/) which suggested `pingInterval + pingTimeout` should equal less than 55 seconds in order to avoid this error. Therefore trying this on your server should address the issue:

```
import SocketIO from 'socket.io';
const sio = SocketIO(server, {
    pingInterval: 15000,
    pingTimeout: 30000,
});
```

Also, [Heroku recommends having the Session Affinity feature enabled](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets#option-2-socket-io) when using socket.io, which you can do via the command line:

```
heroku features:enable http-session-affinity
```

Comment: That's what I did back then and yes it did the trick, although i had to switch `transports` to use exclusively websockets as well.

Comment: Hi @NikKyriakides, one quick advice: it's safer to let socket-io establish an HTTP connection with polling transport and then switch to a WebSocket one when it validates that it's safe to do it https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-websocket-transport-only

Comment: @ahaurat, that's a good solution when the problem is related to the server having a lower timeout threshold for new connection or a lower timeout for idle requests. However, Heroku has a 30secs timeout limit for new requests and a 55secs timeout for "idle" requests. The actual problem described by Nik is a Heroku Router "false positive". I'm leaving this here because I see a lot of people wondering what those errors are. Hope this helps.