# Heroku WebSocket (socket.io) 'Idle Connection' H15 - Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku

I don't know how to get rid of the `Idle connection` error. It used to be worse, but it's still happening every hour or so. Here is the log I get with Papertrail:

```
Aug 09 23:07:25 heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/a/login/" host=... request_id=f99431f8-9ce9-4e1e-b16f-0ae2b50870ab fwd="74.210.150.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=258ms status=304 bytes=305  
Aug 09 23:07:26 heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/js/auth.js" host=app.sofiatutors.com request_id=12896c98-9803-4161-bf5b-06028123ff86 fwd="74.210.150.28" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=240  
Aug 09 23:07:56 heroku/router: at=info method=POST path="/api/email/reset/qEUsZwkRvp750OBgCFuXImiCWPhQbTD0vFVaGEyCZJJXEJGpm6Gi7cgKWsLqHOTusRHieWyVgEbqe6T5qH7wCJT9ROToeHnINhTDvq5unWT6r7fwh4ha59PlQVwB6TmS" host=app.sofiatutors.com request_id=ae44cd3d-cb06-42bd-8948-9e8ca8273ebe fwd="74.210.150.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=395ms status=200 bytes=426  
Aug 09 23:08:11 heroku/router: at=info method=POST path="/api/email/reset/qEUsZwkRvp750OBgCFuXImiCWPhQbTD0vFVaGEyCZJJXEJGpm6Gi7cgKWsLqHOTusRHieWyVgEbqe6T5qH7wCJT9ROToeHnINhTDvq5unWT6r7fwh4ha59PlQVwB6TmS" host=app.sofiatutors.com request_id=a0ed9edc-a561-4518-a61c-3d22fa9445aa fwd="74.210.150.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=214ms status=200 bytes=426  
Aug 09 23:08:21 heroku/router: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket" host=app.sofiatutors.com request_id=a5db86f2-7561-44db-bc1d-22ae69ac3a30 fwd="74.210.150.28" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=56301ms status=503 bytes=279
```

At the beginning, I thought that it was because the user was uploading a file or something like that but it's not the case. From what I see, the user is simply resetting his password. What's even weirder is that the WebSocket isn't used at this point except for the ping pong!

I didn't find any solutions online. I am using a CNAME record for my DNS. I keep the connection alive by sending `ping` to my server which answers by `pong` every 20 seconds with my WebSocket. I force my connection to WebSocket in Socket.io (I was getting more idle connections with XHR-polling).

This is my **client code** :

```
const socket_url = environment.indexOf('dev') === -1 ? "wss://" + window.location.host :  'ws://localhost:3000';

var socket = io.connect(socket_url, { transports : ["websocket"] });
let socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, "server/");

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log("L'utilisateur s'est connecté à un Socket.");
  // Init code
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log("Déconnexion au socket.")
});

socket.emit('ping');

socket.on('pong', function() {

  console.log("pong", new Date().toString());

  var to = setTimeout(function(){

    console.log("ping", new Date().toString());
    socket.emit('ping');
    clearTimeout(to)

  },20000);

});
```

And my server code (Node.JS with Express) :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join-auth', function (data) {

      socket.join(data.session); // We are using room of socket io
      var room = data.session;

      socket.on('ping', function(){
        // console.log("ping pong", new Date().toString())
        io.sockets.in(room).emit('pong');
      })

      // The rest of my socket
```

I know Heroku has a 55 seconds timeout for WebSockets but I simply don't understand why connection get idle or how to fix it. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Having the same problem... did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @BloodShura No, I never found a solution and Heroku support wasn't very helpful. Since then, I switched to DigitalOcean and it works way better. But I realized that I still lose the connexion when the CPU/RAM are high.

Comment: Hi guys, I was facing this mistery too and after a lot of debugging and testing, I realized it is a Heroku Router "problem", not really a bug in the app. I answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728030/heroku-h15-error-on-web-socket-close/59941248#59941248 in case it's useful for anyone.